# TypeError: Cannot find function createHTMLDocument in object

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

Selenium WebDriver (Java) gives the following error when running tests using a headless browser (either Firefox or Chrome) however, it runs without a problem when using a visible browser (e.g. Firefox).

```
      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function createHTMLDocument in object [object DOMImplementation]. (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js#4)
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about an error like this and trawling through SO hasn't turned up anything.

I'm new to Selenium WebDriver so I'm hoping it's just something obvious I've missed.

```
//If intialised like this it fails with the above error
webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38, true);
webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

//If initialised like this, it works
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Probably it is using different versions of firefox under the hood. We suffered a lot from unstable firefox behavior also between version steps, so I would look into that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your version of HtmlUnit misses an implementation of DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument(). Please try with the latest version or even better with the latest snapshot.

Comment: Thanks! This set me on the right track. I ended up changing my reference to WebDriver to HtmlUnitDriver and using .setJavascriptEnabled(false). I'm now getting an intermittent socket exception error which I suspect is an entirely different issue all together...